# Why the bridge0 has a Ethernet port address? it refers to what?

Tags: networking, bridge

I use `ifconfig -a` list the bridge0 detail information:

```
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 7
    eflags=41000000<ECN_ENABLE,FASTLN_ON>
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
            hostfilter 0 hw: 0:0:0:0:0:0 ip: 0.0.0.0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
            hostfilter 0 hw: 0:0:0:0:0:0 ip: 0.0.0.0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
    state availability: 0 (true)
    qosmarking enabled: yes mode: none
    low power mode: disabled
    multi layer packet logging (mpklog): disabled
    routermode4: disabled
    routermode6: disabled
```

I have several questions about the detail info.

1. what's the `ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0` meaning? is it a MAC address? as we know a Ethernet port should have one. but why the bridge0 have one?  is it refers to a Ethernet port of it, but which?
2. are the members `en1` `en2` are attached on bridge0?

or is there any link for introducing it?

---

**EDIT-01**

If the en1 and en2 attached on bridge0, I think the bridge0 should have two more MAC address of each. is it the `hw: 0:0:0:0:0:0`?

and I am familiar with Switch, the MAC address is on a Ethernet port, but `ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0` do not into a ethernet port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0 meaning? is it a MAC address? as we know a Ethernet port should have one. but why the bridge0 have one? is it refers to a Ethernet port of it, but which?

First, the device `bridge0` simultaneously represents two things: the actual L2 bridge and a virtual Ethernet port that connects *the host OS itself* to that bridge.

Individual bridge/switch ports generally do not have their own MAC addresses, but devices connected to them do. So in this case, `82:13:08:b0:ec:c0` is the MAC address of the host OS connected to the bridge. If bridge0 had an IP address, the OS would send the IP packets using that MAC address.

But also note that even when bridges/switches don't need to speak IP, they are still not completely passive devices on the network: they often use STP (Spanning Tree Protocol) to interact with other bridges on the network for avoiding loops, so each STP-speaking bridge of course needs its own MAC address for the STP packets. (The "Configuration:" subsection of your ifconfig output consists entirely of STP-related parameters; the 'id' is blank because STP is disabled.)

So `82:13:08:b0:ec:c0` is the bridge's MAC address when it speaks STP. (More advanced "enterprise" switches might also speak LLDP, 802.1X, and various other link-layer protocols that require the switch to have its own MAC address.) Although again, technically it's the bridge's host OS that does this – connected to the bridge through an internal port (this is true even on physical Ethernet switches; they have a so-called "CPU port").

---

It seems from your output that you're running macOS, or at least some BSD-like OS. If that is the case, don't mind much the comments about "ifconfig being obsolete" – while they are very true *on Linux* (where the 'ip' and 'bridge' tools are preferred), none of it applies to the BSDs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes  that is a MAC address.  A bridge interface acts like a virtual ethernet interface, so it needs the same characteristics as one.
2. Yes.  (I note the tool you are using is not really appropriate for dealing with details of beidges, and has been deprecated).

Comment: please recommend the appropriate tool. and please check my post edit.

Comment: brctl (bridge utils) or if you have network manager, nmcli

Comment: @davidgo: You're talking about Linux tools, but OP is apparently running macOS.

Answer (score 0):

A Bridge is a Layer 2 device so it handles all of its traffic by sending and receiving frames addressed by MAC address. you are correct, the Ethernet address is a MAC.

A bridge connects one or more network segments together, and it is quite likely that it is connecting the network segment connected to en1 with the segment connected to en2. we cannot tell for sure based on ifconfig.

you can find more info on bridges and how to control them here: https://goyalankit.com/blog/linux-bridge

Comment: please check my edit. I don't understand why the bridge only have one independent MAC address, and it connect to who?

Comment: in terms of normal traffic processing, I don;'t believe that a bridge really needs a MAC, except for receiving direct traffic like responses to broadcasts or whatever. generally speaking a bridge will learn the MACs of the devices on either side, and if a frame comes in on en1 that is destined for a MAC known to exist on the other side of the bridge, the bridge will just send the frame out the en2. bridges are really just "dumb" devices, with simple functions to optimize network utilization, and avoid loops/storms. unlike a tunnel, a bridge doesn't need two identities.